# How to do a transparent background color on text?

Tags: html, css, text, transparent

Look at [http://www.sydsvenskan.se/](http://www.sydsvenskan.se) or just look at the image bellow, and check their big image with text overlaying it at the top of the site.

They have a black transparent background on the text, but the text itself isn't transparent. How do they accomplish this?

If I try to add transparency on a text block with background set, the text gets transparent as well.

[image]

Comment: They're using a transparent `.png`, but there are alternatives.

Comment: If you know any, please share :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They use a semi-transparent PNG background image.

```
.supertop div h1 a {
color: #FAFAFA;
background-image: url("/template/ver2-0/gfx/trans_black.png");
padding: 2px 10px;
line-height: 60px;
}
```

this is the safest approach at the moment, as long as not all browsers support `rgba` colours.

It will be an opaque grey in IE6, which doesn't support alpha transparency.

Comment: Thanks! Why did I not think about that, so easy! :D

Answer (score 2):

CSS 3 introduces [rgba colours](http://dorward.me.uk/www/css/alpha-colour/). Use one for the background.

For compatibility with browsers that do not support it you can fallback to solid colours or translucent PNGs.

Answer (score 1):

Background image is the key http://www.sydsvenskan.se/template/ver2-0/gfx/trans_black.png

Answer (score 1):

it has a black transparent background image, *firebug* it and you'll see it.

Answer (score 1):

Use RGBa!

```
.alpha60 {
/* Fallback for web browsers that doesn't support RGBa */
background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
/* RGBa with 0.6 opacity */
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
/* For IE 5.5 - 7*/
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000, endColorstr=#99000000);
/* For IE 8*/
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000, endColorstr=#99000000)";
}
```

via http://robertnyman.com/2010/01/11/css-background-transparency-without-affecting-child-elements-through-rgba-and-filters/